# Get the window handle for the context menu?

Tags: winapi, uiaccessibility

I'm using MSAA for some automation.

Unlike all other MSAA elements I cannot iterate over the children of the desktop window (even though I can get the count of windows with `accChildCount`).

So I'm looking for another way to get the context menu MSAA object. My latest idea is if I can get the HWND of the Context menu then I can use [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the MSAA Object. The difficulty is, how do you get the HWND of the context menu?

Currently my only work around is using UIAutomation to retrieve the HWND, but I feel this may be quite wasteful... Are there any other Windows32 functions which can return a handle to the context menu?

Comment: How do you even know a context menu is open?

Comment: @conio Because I invoked it. If one has a way to get the HWND of the context menu, then one can also find out if it's open using that of course.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN says you can use `FindWindowEx( NULL, NULL, MAKEINTATOM(0x8000), NULL );` to find the menu window.

Comment: Interesting! I will try this! Thanks!